# Открытие файла по URI

Tags: c#

Имеется такая запись в RtBox. Как осуществить открытие файла прямо из RtBox по заданному Uri (`file:/G:/...txt`)

> `file:/G:/%D0%9C%D0%9E%D0%99%20%D0%94%D0%98%D0%9F%D0%9B%D0%9E%D0%9C/%D0%94%D0%98%D0%9F%D0%9B%D0%9E%D0%9C/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%20%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%A2%D0%92/%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%81/ProgDVB/ChannelNameTable.txt#S.PosNIDTIDSIDCrypProvNameChannel name1921334181"PREMIERE""PREMIERE Direkt Portal"1921331501"PREMIERE""arena home"192331001"PREMIERE""PREMIERE Direkt 5C"192342081"PREMIERE""PREMIERE Direkt`

**Добавлено из комментария**.

Я делал таким образом. Так получается только в ListBox, а мне обязательно в RtBox:

```
p = new Uri(p).LocalPath;

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(p).WaitForExit();
```

Comment: я делал таким образом!! Так получается только в ListBox мне обязательно  в RtBox!! 

            p = new Uri(p).LocalPath;

            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(p).WaitForExit();

Answer (score 1):

Сам нашел решение! Добавил обработчик события и конвертировал Uri. Все работает.

```
void rtBox_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    string linkmetni;
    linkmetni = new Uri(e.LinkText).LocalPath;    
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(linkmetni).WaitForExit();
}
```